How to define a method for a block in Ruby?
I'm trying to make this work (it's a simplified example):
console do
  say "Hello"
  say "Bye"
end

Here, I want somehow make the say method available only inside the block provided to the console method. How would you define the console method, assuming that say simply prints the argument to stdout?

You can use instance_eval to evaluate the block in the context of an object that responds to say. That object could be an instance of a class providing your DSL, for example:
class DSL
  def say(arg)
    puts arg
  end
end

def console(&block)
  dsl = DSL.new
  dsl.instance_eval(&block)
end

console do
  say "Hello"
  say "Bye"
end


def console(&block)
  Class.new do
    def say(message)
      puts message
    end
  end.new.instance_eval(&block)
end

Or
def console(&block)
  context = Object.new

  context.define_singleton_method(:say) do |message|
    puts message
  end

  context.instance_eval(&block)
end

Then
console do
  say "Hello"
  say "Bye"
end

